# detecting value change of a hidden field using Razor, then calling the JavaScript function onchange event

Tags: javascript, html, razor

How would I change the value of a hidden field using Razor, and then call the JavaScript function alert("hello")  onchange event.

For some reason the code below is not working...

```
<input id="trigger" name="trigger" type="hidden"  value="6" onchange="alert("hello") />

@{  
 var hiddenfieldvalue = @Html.Hidden("trigger", "5"); // it would be better to retrieve the value at first which is 6, rather than assigning it to 5.

 // the code below should cause the hidden field value to change, which will then call alert("hello")

    if(hiddenfieldvalue.ToString() == "2")
        @Html.Hidden("value","3");
    else
        @Html.Hidden("value", "2");


}

 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
   <title>Add Numbers</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <style type="text/css">
     body {background-color: beige; font-family: Verdana, Arial;
        margin: 50px; }
     form {padding: 10px; border-style: solid; width: 250px;}
   </style>
 </head>
<body> </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have several misunderstandings here.

Firstly, the razor code runs to completion serverside, and the final rendered page is delivered to the browser which then runs the javascript code - there is no interaction between the two other than whatever parts of the javascript the razor code outputs.

Also `Html.Hidden()` writes out the HTML for a hidden form field - at no point would it's .ToString() evaluate to just the value.  Also, if prefixed by `@` it outputs at the point you have that line, this your code will always output the HTML for a hidden field with the name `value` and the value `2` **BEFORE** the DOCTYPE line, due to the if never matching and being positioned before the DOCTYPE.  You would want to move it inside the currently non-existant `<form>` tag although I'd recommend using `@using (Html.BeginForm()) { ... }` to generate that and putting your code dealing with the hidden field within that.

If you wish to detect the change in razor, you can then use that check to surround the output of the javascript code to fire the alert().  Thus either there is no change so that code is never part of the rendered page, or there is a change and the code is output, and run once the page gets to the browser (assuming the client hasn't disabled javascript).

Comment: thank you for your response, however after I put the Html.Hidden logic inside the Html.BeginForm, it still does not work, could you please show me in code what you mean as I am very new to Razor.